# swagger-tools on node: how to serve swagger-ui from basePath

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

using nodejs and swagger-tools v0.8.7 to route endpoints.

"basePath": "/api/myapi" in the api/myapi.json works great, ie: GET, POST, etc... at http://localhost:3000/api/myapi works.

But I still have to access http://localhost:3000/docs/ to get at the UI tool.  How can I serve this from http://localhost:3000/api/myapi/docs/  ?

Same question for serving the yaml at /api/myapy/api-docs instead of /api-docs.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got what i wanted via:

```
app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(
  {
    swaggerUi: '/myapi.json',
    controllers: './lib'
  }));

app.use(middleware.swaggerUi(
  {
    "apiDocs": "/myapi/api",
    "swaggerUi": "/myapi.json"
  }
));
```